# Solving $\int\sqrt{1+(-2ax+b)^2}\;dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, problem-solving, indefinite-integrals

- List item

What solution $$\int\sqrt{1+(-2ax+b)^2}\;dx$$Unable to develop anything ...$~$:'(
I tried completing squares, but can not move much.

Comment: Isn't there an identity like $\sec^2\theta=\tan^2\theta+1$?  Perhaps setting $-2ax+b=\tan\theta$ would be interesting...  Although it is possible that this is one of the insoluble integral types...

Comment: @abiessu I edited the question, I'm sorry.

Comment: Also of note is that $(-2ax+b)^2=(2ax-b)^2$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The substitution $u = -2ax+b$ will get rid of the expression inside the square, so you might as well be dealing with $\int \sqrt{1+u^2}\ du$. This is a very common integral; you can solve it substituting either $u = \tan t$ or $u = \sinh t$.